# Spring Security and Spring Social in different login pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social

I am investigating for a long time an issue I havein my web application where admin signup and login using the traditional approach with username and password and the regular users signup and login using their Facebook account.

The two login forms are in different pages; however, I would like the two to be based on the same Spring Security of the application.

I have several questions that are related to this:

1) I would like to set the user social login form in the landing page while the other in different page. In order to do so I configured the HttpRequest as below, but the landing page was not started.

2) Should I configure two HttpSecurity, one for the traditional login and one for the social login? (the current configuration doesn't work)

3) I would like to define two Authorities, one for the administrators ROLE_ADMIN and one for the regular users ROLE_USER. How do I define a ROLE to the users that logged in using their soaicl account?

**Here is my HttpSecurity configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig{

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {

    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username, password, enabled from Account where username = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                    "select username, authority  from Account where username = ?")
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

}


@Bean
public UserIdSource userIdSource() {
    return new AuthenticationNameUserIdSource();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}

@Bean
public TextEncryptor textEncryptor() {
    return Encryptors.noOpText();
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class BizSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends
        WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
     @Override
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http
     .formLogin()
     .loginPage("/admin")
     .loginProcessingUrl("/admin/authenticate")
     .failureUrl("/admin?param.error=bad_credentials")
     .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")
     .and()
     .authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/","/admin", "/resources/**",
     "/auth/**", "/signin/**", "/signup/**", "/disconnect/**").permitAll()
     .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
     .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
     .and()
     .rememberMe();
     }

     @Bean
        public SocialUserDetailsService socialUsersDetailService() {
            return new SimpleSocialUsersDetailService(userDetailsService());
        }
}

@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class UserSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends
        WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin()
                .loginPage("/")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                .failureUrl("/?param.error=bad_credentials")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/profile")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/user","/admin","/login", "/admin/**",
                        "/resources/**", "/auth/**", "/signin/**",
                        "/signup/**", "/disconnect/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER").and().rememberMe()
                .and().apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
    }

     @Bean
    public SocialUserDetailsService socialUsersDetailService() {
        return new SimpleSocialUsersDetailService(userDetailsService());
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

seems you are mixing some spring security/openid/oauth - spring social concepts.

1. You dont have to provide any custom form for facebook login. Its provided by facebook itself. You can use ProviderSignInController (default implementation)
2. Try to configure admin login with spring security at the beginning. Then mix in facebook.
   loginPage method customize url which will handle POST request of login, so your form need to use it as an 'action' parameter. Also keep in mind that spring security 3.2 has CSRF turned on by default so you also have to pass it by hidden input.
3. ProviderSignInController uses SimpleSignInAdapter to handle signing in. You can set roles in its signIn method and log in facebook user in spring security programmatically. Something like:

   ```
   private class SimpleSignInAdapter implements SignInAdapter {
   public String signIn(String userId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest request) {
       UserProfile userProfile = connection.fetchUserProfile();
       User user = userRepository.findByUsername(userProfile.getEmail());
       Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
       authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
       Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, authorities);
       SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
       return null;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read that there another method for implementing this by using the filter SpringSocialConfigurer. How do I set the Role in such case, or I don't need it?